# Executing JupyterLab non-python notebook from command line

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub, jupyter-lab

I've been looking into [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) as a possible way of programmatically executing notebooks, but it isn't clear to me that it will work with different Kernels.

I'm planning on using JupyterHub + JupyterLab for code development using a number of different kernels, but need to run the "finished" notebooks as executable scripts - are there any tools or techniques that already achieve this?

Comment: Which other kernels do you have in mind?  Have you found anything in the documentation, either for Jupyter itself or for the kernels.  I believe some kernels are developed outside of the Jupyter core.  Except for one or two of the more popular ones (Javascript?) I wouldn't count such a conversion.

Comment: I'm not certain yet but will likely start with a few of the more popular data science languages. So certainly R and Matlab, along with the default Python. The reason I need executables is I'd like to run them at scale across potentially hundreds of cloud VMs, installing even a headless notebook seems inefficient.

Comment: And MATLAB has been installed on those cloud VMs?

Comment: Maybe Matlab was a bad example because of the way those files have to be packaged by Matlab to run on machines without Matlab licences. I doubt the kernel will support such a feature though I've not looked into it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just doing a web search for

```
nbconvert for R
```

gave me a link to:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nbconvertR/versions/1.0.2/topics/nbconvert

and for matlab

https://pypi.org/project/matlab_nbconvert/

The converters are language specific, and depend on who has developed the specific kernels.

https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-script

has an example of `to scrip` for `julia`.  I don't know just how generic that is.  You many have to test it.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I didn't come across these, I must have read hundreds of web pages this week looking for an answer.